# Como guardo un token de jwt en el localStorage

Tags: nodejs

hola hice un login lcuando el usuario inicia sesion genera un token lo iba a guardar en las cookies pero me recomendaron hacerlo en el localStorage, estuve buscando videos y documentacion pero lo que necesito no lo consegui a ver si me pueden ayudar a guardar el token en el localStorage de ante mano gracias, por ahora solo envio el token por console.

```
´´´
       require('dotenv').config();
        const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

       const generateToken = async (user) => {
        return await jwt.sign(
         {
            _id: user._id,
            role: user.role
         },
         process.env.JWT_SECRET,
         {
        expiresIn: "2h"
        }
       )
      }

      const verifyToken = async (token) => {
      try {
        return await jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
      } catch (e) {
      return null
     }
     }

     module.exports = {generateToken, verifyToken}
     const UserModel = require('../models/user');
    const {generateToken} =  require('../helpers/jwtHelper.js');

     const login = async (usuario, password) => {
     const user = await UserModel.findOne({ usuario });
      if (!user) {
      throw new Error('Usuario no encontrado');
      }

     const passwordMatch = await user.comparePassword(password);
      if (!passwordMatch) {
       throw new Error('Contraseña incorrecta');
       }

     const token = await generateToken(user) 
       console.log(token)
       return user;
   

       module.exports = login;
       routes login----------------------------
      const express = require('express');
        const app = express();
        const login = require('../controllers/authController');


            app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
         const { usuario, password } = req.body;
           try {
         const user = await login(usuario, password);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Inicio de sesión exitoso', 
         user });
        } catch (error) {
         res.status(401).json({ message: error.message });
           }
             }); 
            esta es la views del login aunque es solo html 
          <body>
               <section class="form-main">
              <div class="form-conte">
               <div class="box">
                 <h1>Login</h1>
                  <form action="/" method="post" id="loginForm">
                <p>Usuario
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su 
             usuario" name="usuario" required>
                    
                </p>
                <p>Contraseña
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese su 
            Contraseña" name="password" required>
                    
                </p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Ingresar</button>
               </form>
                 </div>
              </div>
          </section>
         </body>
           <script src="login.js"></script>
         </html>
         middlewares del token y rol------------
        const {verifyToken} = require('../helpers/jwtHelper.js')
         const userModel = require('../models/user.js')

          const checkAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
           try {
          //TODO: authorization: Bearer {token}
          const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ').pop()
         const tokenData = await verifyToken(token)

            if (tokenData._id) {
             next()
            } else {
           res.send("No tiene permisos para ingresar").status(403)
            }
            } catch (e) {
           res.send("No tiene permisos para ingresar").status(403)
            }
             }

           const checkAuthRole = (roles) => async (req, res, next) => {
           try {
           const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ').pop()
           const tokenData = await verifyToken(token)
            const userData = await userModel.findById(tokenData._id)

            //TODO: ['admin'].includes('user')
          if([].concat(roles).includes(userData.role)) {
             next()
            } else {
         res.send("No tiene permisos de Role para 
         ingresar").status(403)
              }
        } catch (e) {
        res.send("No tiene permisos de Role para ingresar").status(403)
        }
        }

        module.exports = {checkAuth, checkAuthRole}

                ´´´
```

falta agregarle en las routes de las views para que este en todas las paginas y tambien identifique el token del admin y de los demas usuarios para que no deje ir a ciertas paginas y agregarle un filtro a los demas usuarios

Comment: No puede acceder al local storage desde node js, tienes que usar el js de tu html, tal vez agregarias el código que estas usando para poder ayudarte

Comment: utilizo ejs para las vistas

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ya comparti parte del codigo

Comment: a modo informativo, si el token tiene que viajar siempre, porque no guardarlo en una cookie?

Comment: eso estaba haciendo pero me dijeron que no es muy recomendable guardalo en las cookies

Comment: Muestra cómo estás enviando los *templates* de `ejs`. Falta ver la lógica completa del proceso que realizas para hacer `login`. Desde que recibes la solicitud hasta que la misma es respondida por el servidor. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega todos esos detalles a tu pregunta y podré ayudarte.

Comment: ya subi otros detalles mas

Answer (score 0):

para almacenar en el `localStorage` usas el método `setItem(clave, valor)`

```js
  localStorage.setItem("bgcolor", "red");
  localStorage.setItem("font", "Helvetica");
  localStorage.setItem("image", "myCat.png");
```

y para retomarlos usas el metodo getItem(clave)

```js
  localStorage.getItem("bgcolor"); //red
  localStorage.getItem("font");//Helvetica
  localStorage.getItem("image");//myCat.png
```

Comment: ok muchas gracias lo usare